# What happens to ReFS if I reinstall Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, filesystem-corruption, refs

ReFS seems nice. As far as I know, it is some sort of software RAID. If so, the information is managed by the OS. What happens somehow Windows is corrupted and I reinstall Windows? Is all information on the disks on which ReFS partitions are lost?

Answer (score -2):

If the data is stored on a different partition to the Windows installation then the data wont be lost. But I assume if they were on the same partition it would wipe the data too.

Is that answering your question?

Comment: That's fine, just vote me down, don't respond to me so I can actually try and help!